# Why can some PHP objects be converted to a string

Tags: php, object, tidy

I was looking into PHP tidy and I saw the following code

```
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
// Output
echo $tidy;
```

`Tidy` here is an object. Why isn't this throwing a `Catchable fatal error: Object of class tidy could not be converted to string` error???

Comment: Overriding _toString() :https://coderwall.com/p/nx3bka/magic-method-to-make-an-object-echoable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familliar with tidy, but my guess is, that the object implements the magic method __toString(), as described here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: Right, like the `JavaScript` `Object.toString` method?

Comment: Yes, it's like `Object.toString` in JavaScript.